# Where can I learn more about decentralized identity?

Tags: decentralized-identity

Decentralized Identity is an new form of identity technology and emerging standards based on decentralized/distributed systems - where can you learn more?

Comment: This question is a general info query to kick off the tag that folks can use to gather decentralized identity related issues within SO. Please add any informative content that could help people better understand where to find resources and details that can help them in their development.

Answer (score 2):

Decentralized Identity is an new form of identity technology and emerging standards based on decentralized/distributed systems. There are a few key principles these new technologies incorporate:

1. You own your identifiers (DIDs) - unlike email addresses and usernames, IDs you generate are yours, and you control their PKI state
2. Your data is encrypted and stored in secure personal datastores
3. You can sign cryptographic assertions of proof, claims/credentials, with the keys linked to your DIDs

Resources where you can find more info:

- [Decentralized Identity Foundation](https://identity.foundation)
- [W3C Credentials Community Group](https://www.w3.org/community/credentials/)

Answer (score 2):

> A good self‐sovereign identity system will allow individuals to directly influence how companies, governments, and others correlate our interactions across different services and locations by default. It won’t fix all identity problems nor preclude alternative identity approaches, but it will put the individual in control of most uses of identity and give organizations a simpler, easier, more ethical way to use identity to improve how they provide services and products. When successful, it will not only enable individuals to exercise greater control over how companies and governments keep track of us, it will also illuminate those situations where self‐sovereign identity is restricted, facilitating a conversation about when and where such limits are appropriate.

- [Joe Andrieu -A Technology‐Free Definition of Self‐Sovereign Identity](https://github.com/jandrieu/rebooting-the-web-of-trust-fall2016/blob/master/topics-and-advance-readings/a-technology-free-definition-of-self-sovereign-identity.pdf)

[Decentralized-id.com](https://decentralized-id.com) is a web-directory of curated lists on topics related to decentralized identity.

Notable pages on the site:

There is a [History](https://decentralized-id.com/history/) section covering the history behind decentralized identity separated between three time-periods [2000-2009](https://decentralized-id.com/history/2000-2009/), [2010-2014](https://decentralized-id.com/history/2010-2014/) and [2015-2019](https://decentralized-id.com/history/2015-2019/).

Some early papers that inspired and led to the current work on decentralized-id:

- [The Dataweb: An Introduction to XDI](https://decentralized-id.com/literature/dataweb-introduction-to-xdi/)

> The goal of XDI is to enable data from any data source to be identified, exchanged, linked, and synchronized into a machine-readable dataweb using XML documents just as content from any content source can linked into the human-readable Web using HTML documents today.

- [Augmented Social Network](https://decentralized-id.com/literature/augmented-social-network/) 2003

> The Augmented Social Network is a proposal for a “next generation” online community that would strengthen the collaborative nature of the Internet, enhancing its ability to act as a public commons that engages citizens in civil society. The ASN creates an infrastructure for trusted relationships...

The main focus of decentralized identity is to build solutions based on common standards to create a path towards wide interoperability and enable users to integrate credentials wherever they'd like, without needing the credential issuer in the middle of that transaction.

As such [Web Standards](https://decentralized-id.com/#web-standards) is the largest category on the site, with information on many of the standard bodies, working groups, and related specifications.

**Outside of Decentralized-id.com** you may also appreciate these resources

- [SSI Meetup](http://ssimeetup.org/) is probably the best resource to learn both broadly and deep into a variety of related topics, having lots of presentations available in multiple formats.
- [Internet Identity Workshop](https://internetidentityworkshop.com/) is a workshop that happens bi-annually and been instrumental in the development of identity tech (such as OAuth) and also been working towards decentralized identity from the start. [IIW-Wiki](http://iiw.idcommons.net/)
- [Rebooting the Web of Trust](https://www.weboftrust.info/) works on [whitepapers](https://www.weboftrust.info/papers.html), and incubates [specs and reports](https://www.weboftrust.info/specs.html) in decentralized identity.
- [Phil Windley](https://www.windley.com/) (IIW Co-Founder) has probably got the best and longest-running blog in decentralized identity.